# Different RAW query results from django.db.connection and cx_Oracle

Tags: django, oracle, cx-oracle

I executed the following query from my Django project.

```
from django.db import connection
        balance_query = "SOME SQL QUERY"

        with connection.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute(balance_query)
            balance_data = cur.fetchall()
            print(balance_date)
```

Then I get result after print as
(1, 'F', ***77259668***)
(9, 'R', '24153')

The bold value is wrong

**But**

When I execute same query with following query

```
import cx_Oracle
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('host', 'post', service_name='name')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'user', password='pwd', dsn=dsn_tns)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(balance_query)

for r in c:
    print(r)
```

Then it shows correct values which are following

(1, 'F', ***'77244730'***)
(9, 'R', '24153')

**Only one value is differentiating which I marked bold and italic**.
Backend DB is Oracle and I am using same instance with same credentials for both connections.
It is only happening for one user, for all other users query gives same result with **cx_oracle** and **django.connection.cursor**

Comment: I do not know what was the issue but we fixed it making changes in my SQL query
I replaced 
`if trunc(p_order_date) < '11-FEB-2021' then
.........
.........
endif
`
with
`if trunc(p_order_date) < to_date('11-FEB-2021','DD-MON-RRRR') then
.............
.............
endif
`
and it fixed now

Comment: Seems like the issue is related to the current `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` value is not being `DD-MON-RRRR` within NLS settings, which might be queried by using `SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters`,even though we cannot see the query.

Comment: But the issue is occurring for only 2 records. Rest of the records works fine despite same date

Comment: Have you checked `nls_timestamp_format` too?